# Excel VBA Loop-Implementation to Clear All Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops, worksheet

I'm attempting to clear all the sheets in a workbook from row 3 down.  I've accomplished it like this:

```
With Sheets("Wizard Sheets Missing in Import")
    .Rows("3:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With

With Sheets("Import Sheets Missing in Wizard")
    .Rows("3:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With

With Sheets("Items Missing from Wizard")
    .Rows("3:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With

With Sheets("Items Missing from Imports")
    .Rows("3:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```

but would like to implement a loop if possible.  I tried this and it only clears the active sheet and none of the other sheets, even though it's being told to loop through the sheets (as far as I'm aware):

```
For Each vWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With ActiveSheet
        Rows("3:" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
Next
```

Any ideas on how to make a more stream-lined loop for this process?

Comment: In your loop you are always saying delete the data on the `ActiveSheet` but never changing which sheet is active. However, you generally want to avoid activating anything, so @braX 's solution deletes the data without activating it.

Comment: If there is no formatting but just contents to be cleared, you might want to use `.ClearContents` rather than `.Delete`

Comment: jcarroll - isn't "Next" in the context of the "For Each" activating the next worksheet to perform the next action?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the suggestion!  I'll take this into account.

Comment: @user4333011 No -- VBA code can refer to a nonactivated object without activating it. It happens all the time (or, at least it should since activate/select type code tends to be slower than need be).

Comment: Adding to Johns comment for `ClearContents` - clearing the contents of a cell will not muck up any references to that cell, while deleting the cell could cause `#REF!` errors on any formula that uses the cell that's been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to look more like this

```
For Each vWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    vWorksheet.Rows("3:" & vWorksheet.Rows.Count).Delete
Next
```

Comment: Invalid or unqualified reference error thrown on ".Rows"

Comment: added qualified reference.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, braX - you got the first working solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClearAllWorksheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Offset(2).Rows.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

---

- Clears only rows with data, and doesn't `Activate` or `Select` objects
- Works only on the file where the code is running specifically - ThisWorkbook
- Works only on the [Worksheets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/frice/2007/12/05/excels-worksheets-and-sheets-collection-whats-the-difference/) - doesn't include

  - Chart Sheets
  - Macro sheets (Excel 4.0 XLM files)
  - Dialog sheets (Excel 5.0)

Comment: "1004: Delete Method or Range Class failed" when I attempted to integrate this.  I tried ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets because I opened this file and it is not the workbook the code is in, and it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I pasted the wrong code.  Try this one.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim n As Integer

n = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For x = 1 To n
    Sheets(x).Rows(3 & ":" & Sheets(x).Rows.Count).Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Subscript out of range.  Not sure what you're going for, but there is no "Sheet1" in my workbook.

Comment: Hi Chuck, thanks for offering this solution.  This works, too, so I gave it a point up!